# Form Validation for opening and closing time php

Tags: php, forms, validation, time

I'm wondering how would I set the user to input preferred starting time and end time within the range of 9:00 to 20:00 but I think the problem with my code is that the variable type is incorrect.

This is the form input:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label>Start Time:<br></label>
       <input type="time" name="starttime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST['starttime']?>" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>End Time:<br></label>
       <input type="time" name="endtime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST['endtime']?>" required>
     </div>
```

and for the php code that will process the data:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo $open = "9:00";   #declaration for the opening time
            echo " - ";
            echo $close = "20:00";  #declaration for the closing time
            echo "<br>";
            echo $starttime = $_POST['starttime']." - ";
            echo $endtime = $_POST['endtime'];


            echo "<br>time elapsed: ".$total_time = $endtime - $starttime;

            if($starttime>$open){
              echo "Restaurant is open at these hours";
            }else{

            #this part validates the time range after the user's preferred time is within the operating hours of the resto
                      if($total_time > 4){
                      echo "<script>alert('Time Range is too large. Max stay is 4 hours')</script>";
                    } elseif($total_time<1) {
                      echo "<script>alert('Time Range is small.')</script>";
                    }else{
                      echo "oks";
                    }
              echo "string";
            }


          }
```

The error is that it does not go to the else statement, and I think it is because of the parsing of the variables and comparison issues. Is there any way where I can convert the two variables in order to create a greater than or less than comparison?

Comment: You're mixing echo with variable setting, which is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert the strings vars to float before comparison. Personal thing, but I don't trust PHP to compare what is the bigger number inside a string.

And I would change

if($starttime>$open){

To
Something like: starttime = (float)$startime; The same for $open.
if($starttime>=$open){

This answer should be just a comment, but I do not have starts enough to to it yet. Sorry about that.